# TableLayout not shown properly

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, android-styles

I'm having trouble with the layout of my Android app.
The graphical preview editor shows me an image like (and this is how I want it to look like):

[image]

I am using a table layout that looks like this:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
          style="@style/leftColumn"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Branche" />

        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textViewBranche"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         style="@style/rightColumn"
          android:text="Branche"
    />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- ... -->

    <style name="leftColumn">
        <item name="android:background">#2B60DE</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>


    </style>

    <style name="rightColumn">
         <item name="android:background">#C0C0C0</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

If I run my app it looks like this:
[image]

As you can see only one text view is displayed. I would like the table layout to have 2 columns (just like in the preview). The first one (blue) indicating what I am displaying and the second (grey) the information provided by my adapter. However I only see the provided information of my adapter (in this case "sonstige (others)". So basically I only see the right column.
I have no idea why I can't see the content of the first text view (respectively the first row).
I played around with some properties like layout_width and layout_height but it doesn't change.

I'm running this app on my S3.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I'm not sure if it is causing this particular issue or not, but your TextViews should have an `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` set.

Comment: I updated the code above. Unfortunately the problem is still the same. I am confused because at least I would expect to see something of the first text view.